# Angular 2 nested form set value

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I am using angular formbuilder to create a nested form. How do I set nested form `quantity` field value for each form group within `updateValue()` function in following code.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.fastPostingForm = this.fb.group({
      Charges: this.fb.array([
        this.initCharge()
      ])
    });
}

initCharge(){
     return this.fb.group({
      room: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required],
    });
 }

 UpdateValue(i) {
    this.fastPostingForm.controls.Charges[i].controls['quantity'].setValue(2); // This is not working
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: You are missing one `controls`? `this.fastPostingForm.controls.Charges.controls[i].controls['quantity'].setValue(2);` Maybe consider to pass the nested group as parameter instead of index, so that you don't need to go nuts with those long paths :)

Comment: that give me following error - Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```typescript
(this.fastPostingForm.controls.Charges as FormArray).controls[i].controls['quantity']
                                                    .setValue(2)
```

or

```typescript
this.fastPostingForm.get(['Charges', i, 'quantity']).setValue(2);
```

or

```typescript
this.fastPostingForm.get(`Charges.${i}.quantity`).setValue(2);
                        ^^^
                     backtick
```

or you can even use `patchValue` method on your form:

```typescript
this.fastPostingForm.patchValue({
  Charges: [...Array(i), { quantity: '2' }]
});
```

Comment: Try the first one i updated it. Just copied from wrong place

Comment: first one giving me following error Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: Try `(this.fastPostingForm.controls.Charges as FormArray).controls[i].controls['quantity'].setValue(2);`

Comment: `AbstractControl` doesn't have `controls` property